# uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Tags: jquery, css3, html5, вёрстка

Здравствуйте, возникла следующая проблема. в JS новичок, на уровне ("вывести свой алерт"). Добавил на сайт кастомные вкладки, до этого тестил на десктопе, обнаружил вышеупомянутую ошибку. Нашел тут темы с этой ошибкой, попробовал решить по аналогии - ничего не вышло. Проверил наличие всех классов и id (в моем случае это class и select-selected) - все на месте. С типами вроде бы нигде не напортачил. Скрипт расположен внизу, соответственно все элементы в DOM-е, до его загрузки, есть. Подскажите где я допустил ошибку.

выкладываю строку с ошибкой js

```
a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected"); 
a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Сайт выложен на хостинге по этому адресу: [ссылка на хостинг](http://ds01.kl.com.ua)

Comment: А можно часть проблемного кода выложить здесь?

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/186999)

Comment: неверное использование `custom-select`

Comment: Да, я использую custom-select, но на сайте он работает как надо, может я что недосмотрел?

Comment: `selElmnt` - `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за пинки в нужном направлении, ошибка чисто механическая, в selElmnt пропустил букву, исправил, работает.